# How to get a custom value using the method Auth in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, when i want to get the current user ID, i use this logic bellow:

```
public function showuserid() {

    $userid = Auth::id(); //this is the simplest way i found of how to get the current user's id

    return view('perfil/mostrarid')->with('mostrarid',  $userid);

}
```

My problem is, my table 'users' in my database, has an extra column called 'credencial'.

I tried to do `$userid = Auth::credencial();` but it doesn't work and i get an error:

> Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::credencial does not exist.

Can i get that value using Auth somehow? Is there any other way, as simple as Auth, to get the value?

Comment: Try Auth::user()->credencial

Comment: Auth::user()->credencial doesn't work. I get this following error: "Trying to get property 'credencial' of non-object"

Comment: But is an autethicated user wich send the request? Auth::id() will not work also if there is not an authenticated user https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Comment: Auth::id() works because the user is authenticated. Auth::credencial() does not work because 'credencial' is a custom column that i put in 'users' table.

Comment: `Auth::credencial()` deosn't works because credencial it's not an Auth method. What I suggest was this `Auth::user()->credencial`. And what I mean it's if `Auth::user()` reurns null, `Auth::id()` will return null too. If it's there an authenticated user , `Auth::user()` will return the user table fields

Comment: Sorry, i checked again and seems like Auth::user()->credencial works. I totally thought i tried that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, my table 'users' in my database, has an extra column called 'credencial'.

You need to access a logged-in user's property. To do so, try this:

```
$credential = Auth::user()->credential;
```

Now, in order to avoid to throw the error:

> Trying to get property 'credencial' of non-object

Make sure that your user is logged-in. You could do this checking it first:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    $credential = Auth::user()->credential;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what happened. Before i posted the question, i tried Auth::user()->credential and it wasn't working. Now that i checked again, seems like Auth::user()->credential works fine. I tested with the user logged in all the time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There was surely a typo in your code. ```Auth::user()``` gives you access to the user's field in the database.